# findAll never return null in sequelize

Tags: express, sequelize.js

I am using findAll query to retrieve data from my table. Now even if there is no data it does not return null and due to that I am not able to display message if records are not found. Is there any way we can do this?My code looks like this:

```
Model.findAll().then(function(success){if(success){res.json(success);}else{res.send(error);}});
```

Answer (score 5):

Apparently `findAll()` returns an empty array if there is no data. So just `array.length === 0` would be enough.

Answer (score 1):

Feeling stupid. Done with result.length==0

Comment: elaborate please and accept as own answer, will help others